# Place 3D mesh file in front of Camera ARKit (objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arkit

I am developing an iOS app using ARKit. I want to place a 3D object in front of the device (i.e. ARCamera).

**My current code:**

```
ARFrame* currentFrame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame;
matrix_float4x4 translation = matrix_identity_float4x4;
translation.columns[3][2] = -1.52; // Translate 5 feet in front of camera
translation.columns[3][1] = -1.22; // Translate 4 feet below the camera

node.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation);

node.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 0, 0, 0);
node.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
```

**I have following question:**

- Is is the correct code to place a 3D object in front of ARCamera (front and below the camera)?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place an `SCNNode` in front of the camera (assuming you want it to remain locked) in that position you can do this:

```
node.position = SCNVector3(0,-1,-1)
```

*This would set the node 1m below, and 1m away from the Camera.*

If you just want something 'locked' to the center of the screen you can also use:

```
scnView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(node)
```

If you want to place an `SCNNode` directly infront of the camera using it's `current.frame` you can use this:

```
    /// Adds An SCNNode 3m Away From The Current Frame Of The Camera
   func addNodeInFrontOfCamera(){

    guard let currentTransform = augmentedRealitySession.currentFrame?.camera.transform else { return }

    let nodeToAdd = SCNNode()
    let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
    boxGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    nodeToAdd.geometry = boxGeometry

    var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4

     //Change The X Value
     translation.columns.3.x = 0

     //Change The Y Value
     translation.columns.3.y = 0

     //Change The Z Value
     translation.columns.3.z = -3

    nodeToAdd.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(currentTransform, translation)
    augmentedRealityView?.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeToAdd)

}
```

The `var` augmentedRealityView is an `ARSCNView`.

**Update In Objective C**:

```
-(void)addNodeInFrontOfCamera{

SCNBox * cube = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:0.1 height:0.1 length:0.1 chamferRadius:0.0];
cube.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor redColor];
SCNNode *cubeNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:cube];
[self.sceneView.scene.rootNode addChildNode:cubeNode];

matrix_float4x4 cameraTransform = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame.camera.transform;
matrix_float4x4 translation = matrix_identity_float4x4;

//Change The X Value
translation.columns[3][0] = 0;

//Change The Y Value
translation.columns[3][1] = 0;

//Change The Z Value
translation.columns[3][2] = -3;

cubeNode.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(cameraTransform, translation);

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want to place the node in front of ARCamera and not 3D camera of Scenekit. With your current code if I move my device and try to place the 3D node then the node will not spawn in front of the camera.

Comment: Have updated my answer... Apologies it is in swift though :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you provide Objective-c code? I also want to translate the node in y direction. How can I do it in Objective-C?

Comment: Have updated the main function to Obj-C including how to change x,y,z values. Please mark as correct if it all works :)

Comment: Thank you for the code. How can I apply the ARcamera rotations to the node?

Comment: That’s another question :)

Comment: Please check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151332/apply-arcamera-rotation-transform-to-node-arkit